# How do I kill all programs?

Tags: 14.04

I'm experiencing hanging for the first time.

How do I kill all programs in such a case. Secondly please inform me how I can find out whether my laptop is infected with virus or not. I am not using any antivirus package at present.

Comment: 1) One question per post. Please ask the Antivirus issue in a different question. --- 2) Both questions could be solved by a quick google research for old questions here on askubuntu. --- 3) To perform an emergency reboot on Linux systems (better than hard reset, helps avoiding HDD failure because it gives the kernel time to flush and sync cached data first, etc.) you press and keep holding the ALT+SYSRQ keys, then you additionally hit the keys R, E, I, S, U, B, one after the other waiting some time after each. Watch e.g. your HDD access LED. When activity stops, press the next key.

Answer (score 1):

To kill all the processes that you have the permission to kill,open terminal and run the command

`kill -15 -1` or `kill -9 -1`.

To learn how to scan read the answer to this question:

[How can I scan for possible viruses on my Ubuntu system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417429/how-can-i-scan-for-possible-viruses-on-my-ubuntu-system)